# NoNetworkAvailable: Unable to create the network. No tenant network is available for allocation

Tags: openstack-neutron

I'm trying to setup a simple control+compute on a single ubuntu node. I'm using devstack. This is the command that fails:

```
neutron net-create --tenant-id 6fad6bf2ae9c49d3b19958abd59f3ce0 private-net
```

And the error is:

```
NoNetworkAvailable: Unable to create the network. No tenant network is available for allocation.
```

here's my relevant config ml2 config:

```
[ml2]
tenant_network_types = flat
extension_drivers = port_security
type_drivers = flat
mechanism_drivers = openvswitch
[ml2_type_flat]
flat_networks = public-physical-net,private-physical-net,dpdk-physical-net
[ml2_type_vlan]
network_vlan_ranges = private-physical-net
[ml2_type_gre]
tunnel_id_ranges = 1:1000
[ml2_type_vxlan]
vni_ranges = 1001:2000
[ml2_type_geneve]
[securitygroup]
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.OVSHybridIptablesFirewallDriver
[agent]
tunnel_types =
root_helper_daemon = sudo /usr/local/bin/neutron-rootwrap-daemon /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf
root_helper = sudo /usr/local/bin/neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf
[ovs]
datapath_type = system
bridge_mappings = public:br-ex
```

this is the ovs:

```
Bridge br-int
    fail_mode: secure
    Port br-int
        Interface br-int
            type: internal
    Port int-br-ex
        Interface int-br-ex
            type: patch
            options: {peer=phy-br-ex}
Bridge br-ex
    Port br-ex
        Interface br-ex
            type: internal
    Port "p255p1"
        Interface "p255p1"
    Port phy-br-ex
        Interface phy-br-ex
            type: patch
            options: {peer=int-br-ex}
ovs_version: "2.0.2"
```

The relevant section of local.conf:

```
# Do not use Nova-Network
disable_service n-net
# Enable Neutron
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,q-svc,q-dhcp,q-meta,q-agt,q-l3

Q_PLUGIN=ml2
Q_ML2_PLUGIN_MECHANISM_DRIVERS=openvswitch

## Neutron options
FIXED_RANGE="10.0.123.0/24"
NETWORK_GATEWAY=10.0.123.1 ##MY
FLOATING_RANGE="10.0.0.0/22"
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=10.0.1.167,end=10.0.1.169
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY="10.0.0.205"

Q_USE_SECGROUP=True
Q_L3_ENABLED=True
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=p255p1
Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC=True
OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex
PUBLIC_BRIDGE=br-ex
OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=public-physical-net:br-ex

Q_ML2_PLUGIN_TYPE_DRIVERS=flat
Q_ML2_TENANT_NETWORK_TYPE=flat
ENABLE_TENANT_VLANS=False
ENABLE_TENANT_TUNNELS=False

PUBLIC_PHYSICAL_NETWORK=public-physical-net
PHYSICAL_NETWORK=private-physical-net
PUBLIC_NETWORK_NAME=public-net
PRIVATE_NETWORK_NAME=private-net
Q_ML2_PLUGIN_FLAT_TYPE_OPTIONS="flat_networks=public-physical-net,dpdk-physical-net,private-physical-net" # CH did not exist
```

Comment: I will add the devstack local.conf soon

Comment: btw running on devstack stable/liberty